# An active directory domain controller ad dc for the domain could not be contacted

Tags: domain-controller

i have create a domain in Windows Server 2019 but the client can't connect .
both pc are connected via VPN .

```
server  have vpn ip **10.8.0.6**
client  have vpn ip **10.8.0.7**

Windows IP Configuration  - CLIENT -

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : pc01
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : localdomain

Unknown adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9 for OpenVPN Connect
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-BF-3E-F2-12
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::71ca:7889:bfa5:b8bb%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.7(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 402718655
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-26-9F-5C-F8-00-0C-29-74-C1-D4
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 1.0.0.1
                                       1.1.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-74-C1-D4
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::64cc:9549:b83a:36c9%7(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 11.0.0.213(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, July 16, 2020 11:18:58 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, July 16, 2020 4:54:07 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 11.0.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 11.0.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 50334761
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-26-9F-5C-F8-00-0C-29-74-C1-D4
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 11.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled




Windows IP Configuration    - SERVER - 

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ServerM1
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : m1.local
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : m1.local

Unknown adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9 for OpenVPN Connect
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-86-27-8B-C5
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.6(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 1.0.0.1
                                       1.1.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-19-99-B2-BB-73
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.8.162(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, July 16, 2020 1:45:15 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, July 17, 2020 1:45:15 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.8.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.8.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.8.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

and i got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymTQo.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point your clients (and servers) DNS Servers (TCP/IP Settings) to the **correct** server. DNS is the foundation of **everything** in ActiveDirectory and your client uses "1.1.1.1" as DNS, which is a cloudflare DNS-Server. I doubt cloudflare has a copy of your private AD DNS Zone.

All AD clients (includes AD DCs) **must** have working DNS Infrastrukture, in your case for the zone `m1.local`.